# One-to-one sequence of elements in set $A$: is it also onto?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Suppose I have a sequence $\{s_n\}$ in $A$. So $s_n$ represents a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose further that this function $s_n$ is one-to-one, so if $n_1 \neq n_2$, $s(n_1) \neq s(n_2)$.

A one-to-one function, surely, need not be onto. Are there conditions on $A$, however, in which the sequence being one-to-one also implies that it is onto? For example, a function $f: A \to A$ is one-to-one if and only if it is onto provided that $A$ is finite. It seems that if we were mapping into $\mathbb{N}$, the fact that the domain and codomain have equal cardinality would intuitively leading to the result that 1-1 implies onto. If it didn't, there exists $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $s(n) \neq m$ for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$, and from there (though I can't think of a way to prove it) it seems that there has to be a repeat at some point if the sets are equal. Perhaps this doesn't work for infinite sets.

Comment: $f(n)=2n$ is a one-to-one function from $\mathbb N$ into itself which is not onto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several one-to-one functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$ that are not onto. For example, $f(n)=n+1$ or $f(n)=2n$, both being examples from the story of [Hilbert's hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel).

---

We can say even more, and that is that in general, the statement

> If $f:A\to A$ is one-to-one, then it is onto

is true if $A$ **if and only if** $A$ is a finite set. Therefore, the *exact* conditions on $A$ you are looking for is that $A$ is finite. You could even say that an alternative definition of "finite" is that a set $S$ is finite if all one-to-one functions from $S$ to $S$ are also onto.